# How to install Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, unixodbc, mssql-tools

I am trying to install Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server using the document provided by Microsoft. Link is https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql

It provides installation steps for Ubuntu and Redhat but not Amazon Linux. To install Microsoft Drivers on Amazon, I followed steps provided for Redhat ( not sure if it is correct). When I run the command

```
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install msodbcsql mssql-tools
```

got the below error

```
Error: Package: msodbcsql-13.1.7.0-1.x86_64 (packages-microsoft-com-prod)
           Requires: unixODBC >= 2.3.1
           Available: unixODBC-2.2.14-14.7.amzn1.i686 (amzn-main)
               unixODBC = 2.2.14-14.7.amzn1
```

The error clearly says that to install msodbcsql, unixODBC version should be >= 2.3.1. But the updated/latest unixODBC package available for amazon is unixODBC-2.2.14.

I need some help to install Microsoft Drivers for PHP on Amazon Linux so that I can use *Sqlsrv* PHP functions to connect SQL server.

PHP7, Apache, and SQL server are already set up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After googling and trying all the ways, I found the answer to my own question.

Instead of using

```
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install msodbcsql mssql-tools
```

I used

```
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install msodbcsql-13.0.1.0-1 mssql-tools-14.0.2.0-1
```

and the issue fixed.

Comment: Just so you know, that version of msodbcsql gave us a lot of trouble with memory leaks. The newest version 13.1 did fix it, but sadly requires a newer unixODBC.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in msodbcsql17, you can follow this answer:

[Install unixODBC >= 2.3.1 on Linux Redhat/CentOS for msodbcsql17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400791/install-unixodbc-2-3-1-on-linux-redhat-centos-for-msodbcsql17/50400792#50400792)

The steps are the following:

> After a long time of research, I have
>   figured out a solution:
>
> 1. Download the unixODBC >= 2.3.1 from any source, as rpm ([Example source](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/unixODBC-2.3.1-11.el7.x86_64.rpm.html))
> 2. Download the msodbcsql17 and mssql-tool as rpm from Microsoft ([Link to Repo](https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/7/prod/)) (**msodbcsql17-17.1.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm** and
>      **mssql-tools-17.1.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm** in my case)
> 3. Transfer the files via ftp (like FileZilla) to the EC2 instance
> 4. Use EC2 terminal and go to the directory of the uploaded files
> 5. Enter `sudo rpm -i unixODBC-2.3.1-11.el7.x86_64.rpm` to install the necessary version (Perhaps, you have to change the version number to
>      the version number of the uploaded file)
> 6. Enter `sudo rpm -i msodbcsql17-17.1.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm`
> 7. Enter `sudo rpm -i mssql-tools-17.1.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm`
> 8. Follow the rest of the Microsoft instruction, like in your question.
> 9. Now you should be able to use ODBC for example with pyodbc in python.