# Uninstall older unixODBC completely and install 2.3.2 unixODBC in redhat 6.3

Tags: redhat, unixodbc

I am trying to install msodbcsql v13 in redhat 6.3. It shows dependency error for unixODBC(64 bit) >= 2.3.1 needs to be installed before installing msodbcsql.

I tried running below command,

```
 odbcinst -j
```

It shows unixODBC 2.3.2 is installed.
Also i tried to some other way,

```
yum provides /usr/lib64/odbcinst.so.2.0.0
```

The above command shows, ODBC version 2.2 is installed.
Also if i run yum local install, it shows unixODBC 32 bit version available in machine.

To remove unixODBC, i tried the below commands. But not works out.

```
yum remove unixODBC
yum erase unixODBC
rpm -e unixODBC*
rpm rpm -qa | grep unixODBC
```

I want to remove all unixODBC available in the machine. And reinstall the actual version which we required.

Comment: try sudo yum remove package

Answer (score 0):

**Manual Installation**

- Remove any older installed version of unixODBC (for example, unixODBC 2.2.11). On Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 or 6, execute the following command: **yum remove unixODBC**. On SUSE Linux Enterprise, **zypper remove unixODBC**.
- Go to http://www.unixodbc.org. Click the **Download** link on the left side of the page to go to the download page. Then click the appropriate link to save the file unixODBC-2.3.0.tar.gz to your computer. UnixODBC-2.3.1 is not supported with this release of the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server.
- On your Linux computer, execute the command: **tar xvzf unixODBC-2.3.0.tar.gz.**
- Change to the unixODBC-2.3.0 directory.
- At a command prompt, execute the command: **CPPFLAGS="-DSIZEOF_LONG_INT=8"**.
- At a command prompt, execute the command: **export CPPFLAGS**.
- At a command prompt, execute the command: **"./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --sysconfdir=/etc --enable-gui=no --enable-drivers=no --enable-iconv --with-iconv-char-enc=UTF8 --with-iconv-ucode-enc=UTF16LE"**.
- At a command prompt (logged in as root), execute the command: **make**.
- At a command prompt (logged in as root), execute the command: **make install**.

For additional info - [visit the site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-driver-manager)

Answer (score 0):

To remove all `unixODBC` related packages, run:

```
sudo yum remove unixODBC*
```

To install newer version of unixODBC, try to install `unixODBC-utf16` package.

Here are the suggested commands:

```
curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/msprod.repo
sudo yum update
sudo yum info unixODBC*
sudo yum install unixODBC-utf16
```

See also: [Install the SQL Server command-line tools on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools).

---

If above won't help, check: [How to install Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server on Amazon Linux AMI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44141081/55075).