# Install unixODBC >= 2.3.1 on Linux Redhat/CentOS for msodbcsql17

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, redhat, pyodbc, unixodbc

I try to install msodbcsql17 on AWS EC2 with CentOS/RedHat (Linux).

These are the steps, I have followed, from Microsoft ([LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#redhat-enterprise-server-6-and-7)):

```
sudo su

#Download appropriate package for the OS version
#Choose only ONE of the following, corresponding to your OS version

#RedHat Enterprise Server 6
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/6/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo

#RedHat Enterprise Server 7
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo

exit
sudo yum remove unixODBC-utf16 unixODBC-utf16-devel #to avoid conflicts
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install msodbcsql17
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install mssql-tools
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo yum install unixODBC-devel
```

The instruction work until the installation of msodbcsql17. I get the following error message:

```
Error: Package: msodbcsql17 (packages-microsoft-com-prod)
           Requires: unixODBC >= 2.3.1
           Available: unixODBC-2.2.14-14.7.amzn1.i686 (amzn-main)
               unixODBC = 2.2.14-14.7.amzn1
```

I think the problem is, that the maximum available version of unixODBC is less then 2.3.1, but how can I install msodbcsql17, to connect with Microsoft?

Comment: How did you know which RedHat repo to download? (6, 7, or 8). Your question makes it look like you downloaded the 6 and 7 repo config, but it says to only do one.

Comment: @falsePockets If you use RedHat Enterprise 6 you need the link with version 6 ".../rhel/6/..." for RedHat Enterprise 7 it's the same. You can figure out the version with the following tutorial: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-determine-rhel-version/

Answer (score 8):

After a long time of research, I have figured out a solution:

1. Download the unixODBC >= 2.3.1 from any source, as rpm ([Example source](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/unixODBC-2.3.1-11.el7.x86_64.rpm.html))
2. Download the msodbcsql17 and mssql-tool as rpm from Microsoft ([Link to Repo](https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/7/prod/)) (**msodbcsql17-17.1.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm** and **mssql-tools-17.1.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm** in my case)
3. Transfer the files via ftp (like FileZilla) to the EC2 instance
4. Use EC2 terminal and go to the directory of the uploaded files
5. Enter `sudo rpm -i unixODBC-2.3.1-11.el7.x86_64.rpm` to install the necessary version (Perhaps, you have to change the version number to the version number of the uploaded file)
6. Enter `sudo rpm -i msodbcsql17-17.1.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm`
7. Enter `sudo rpm -i mssql-tools-17.1.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm`
8. Follow the rest of the Microsoft instruction, like in your question.
9. Now you should be able to use ODBC for example with pyodbc in python.

Instead of `rpm -i`, you can use `yum install` as well

---

UPDATE: Please take a look at the comment from @KnudLarsen!

Comment: Sean Stayn : Better = `# yum install Downloads/unixODBC-2.3.1-11.el7.x86_64.rpm` . I.e. the `rpm` command dosn't handle dependencies. Besides that, the default rpm command, also used by yum is `rpm -Uvh`.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks for your comment! I'm a beginner in Linux, but this is the only way, I could solve my problem. I've updated my answer, with the hint of your comment and hope, that we can help other users out with your additional information.

Answer (score 2):

heres a snippet from my docker file that shows how to install on amazon linux:

```
RUN curl http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/unixODBC-2.3.1-14.el7.x86_64.rpm > /tmp/unixODBC-2.3.1-14.el7.x86_64.rpm
RUN yum -y install /tmp/unixODBC-2.3.1-14.el7.x86_64.rpm 
RUN curl http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/unixODBC-devel-2.3.1-14.el7.x86_64.rpm > /tmp/unixODBC-devel-2.3.1-14.el7.x86_64.rpm 
RUN yum -y install /tmp/unixODBC-devel-2.3.1-14.el7.x86_64.rpm 

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum -y install msodbcsql17
```

bonus if you want pyodbc:

```
RUN yum -y install gcc72-c++ \
    && yum -y install python36-devel \
    && yum -y install zip \
    && yum clean all
RUN python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip 
RUN python3.6 -m pip install pyodbc
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/496#issuecomment-569938591

Comment: For the `yum -y install` part, I get "Cannot open: unixODBC-2.3.1-14.el7.x86_64.rpm. Skipping.". Any idea what's wrong? Is that a file permission issue, or OS incompatibility?